# gitlab-runner shell executor WARNING: Preparation failed: shell /usr/bin/bash not found

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i am trying to set up an oracle cloud ubuntu vm as a gitlab runner instance with a shell executor.

I am getting this error when i try to run a job on it:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (xxx)
  on bob_the_builder_aarch64_shell xxx, system ID: xxx
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:09
ERROR: Preparation failed: shell /usr/bin/bash not found
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: shell /usr/bin/bash not found
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: shell /usr/bin/bash not found
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): shell /usr/bin/bash not found
```

```
WARNING: Preparation failed: shell /usr/bin/bash not found
```

On the Ubuntu vm in tried to check the bash path and it seems to be correct:

```
$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

Tried as well:

```
/bin/bash
```

I also tried sh:

```
$ which sh
/usr/bin/sh
```

But the same outcome..

Here is my config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "bob_the_builder_aarch64_shell"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = xxx
  token = "xxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-05-08T01:17:42Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "/usr/bin/bash"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
```

I also tried running gitlab-runner with sudo and using the config file at `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` with the same settings..

What on earth am i doing wrong / missing here?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Can you try `/bin/bash` ?

Comment: @GillesQuénot forgot to add it to my question initially, i did also try that.

Comment: Can you run `cat config.toml | sed l` to see if you have `\r` somewhere around `/usr/bin/bash` ?

Comment: @GillesQuénot 

`shell = "/usr/bin/bash"$`
`shell = "/usr/bin/bash"`

seems ok to me

Comment: Are you sure you test the good VM/gitlab runner?  Try to list them with `gitlab-runner`

Comment: @GillesQuénot i just tried to ommit the `shell = "/usr/bin/bash"` value and it seems to be executing now.. this is spooky stuff. My problem is solved for now but its still strange that i cant set the shell path!

Comment: Take care, it maybe execute `/bin/sh` by default. Check if you use only POSIX code or not

Comment: @GillesQuénot it seems to be defaulting to bash `Using Shell (bash) executor...`. Thank you for the warning, i looked into what POSIX and the difference between the two shells and learned something new as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shell` configuration key is expected to be just the shell name, e.g., `bash`, not the path to the executable.

So change:

```ini
  shell = "/usr/bin/bash"
```

to

```ini
  shell = "bash"
```

See: [shells supported by GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html)